# Creating a new node shape in NetworkX (Python)

Tags: python, networkx

Is there any way of can create my own networkX node shape (e.g. An oval/rectangle) beyond the standard shapes provided? I presume I would have to go under the hood and alter the original class but not sure which/where

Comment: Why are you re-asking the same question you asked two days ago? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44831535/pygraphviz-vs-networkx-for-custom-shaped-nodes

Comment: It's been deleted